# .push with no user key

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want users to push posts into my RT firebase database, But i'm not interested to save which user key posted the message, Is there a way of doing it ?

don't want these in the picture :

[image]

Comment: That's not user ids, just random keys based on timestamp.

Comment: BTW, user UID never starts with `-` symbol

Comment: There probably is a way to accomplish what you want. But without seeing the code that you've tried so far, it'll be hard to help.